# .MPart does not affect in CSS

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4, eclipse-pde

I tried following CSS if there is effect of color but I could not change the default white color of the Part.

```
.MPartStack { 
swt-maximize-visible: false;
swt-minimize-visible: false; 
swt-mru-visible: true; 
swt-tab-outline: false;
}

.MPart {
background-color: black;
border-color: black;
swt-corner-radius: 0;
}
```

Only Part Stack works and I am unable to see any change reflected from .MPart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a `Composite` in the code for your part to need to set it to inherit the background using

```java
composite.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT);
```

otherwise the part Composite will not pick up the MPart style.

An alternative is to set a CSS class for the controls that you create, like this:

```java
WidgetElement.setCSSClass(control, "your-class-name");
```

Comment: I set   composite.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT);
into PostConstruct  of that Part but still not getting those styles.

Comment: Getting the CSS right is very tricky, I suggest you learn about the e4 'CSS Spy' tool and use that to see how the styles are being applied.

Comment: I tried a lot using CSS spy but somehow, My apps window never gets covered in SPY. There is almost no red box on my apps window. Is there anything extra I am missing to convey to CSS Spy from my app?

Comment: It has been a while since I used CSS Spy. I have added an alternative where you can set a CSS class on your own controls which is often easier.